# Motion Layout <onSwipe> not animating

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I have a scene which has a starting constraints layout and an ending. The problem is , the swipe animation is abrupt. It just transforms start to end and end to start in a single frame and doesnt animate. the Onclick gesture does animate but I want to use the swipe gesture

motionscene.xml inside xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@layout/backdrop_layout_end"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@layout/backdrop_layout_start"
        motion:motionInterpolator="easeInOut"
        motion:transitionDisable="false"
        motion:duration="200">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/toggle"
            motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
            motion:maxAcceleration=".5"
            />

    </Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

layout_start.xml inside layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/backdrop_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/amber_800"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/backdrop_front"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        android:background="@drawable/upper_rounded_corners"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageView
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"

            android:id="@+id/toggle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_adjust"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

layout_end.xml in layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/backdrop_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/amber_800"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/backdrop_front"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"

        android:background="@drawable/upper_rounded_corners"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"

            android:id="@+id/toggle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_adjust"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also , I am using layout_start inside "end" param and layout_end in "start" param in the motion Scene. That is not a typo. If I go the other way around , then swipe down registers toggle up and swipe up registers toggle down. I almost believe there is a bug with this library. Any help appreciated. thanks !

Comment: Even me also facing same problem.If you know any solution please let me know

Comment: wondering if you managed to find a solution?